# Sanity query in an array of references

Tags: sanity, headless-cms

I have an array of articles with array of tags with references:

```
_type: "article",
tags: [
 {
   _id: "123",
   _rev: "123",
   _type: "articleTag",
   key: { _type: "slug", current: "news" },
   title: "News",
   _type: "string" 
 },
 ...
],
```

I'm trying to create a query of all articles contains an array of several tags:

```
*[ _type == "article" && tags[].key.current in *["news, news2"]._id ]{...,"tags": tags[]->}
```

But I get en error:

> No function in() defined for arguments (array, array)

Answer (score 3):

I got help from [sanity-io-land](https://slack.sanity.io/) very fast. They suggested this:

```
*[ _type == "article" && ("news" in tags[]->key.current || "news2" in tags[]->key.current)]{...,"tags": tags[]->}
```